# How to Pull an RSS Feed using XmlPullParser in Android

Tags: android, rss, xmlpullparser, rss-reader

I'm building an RSS reader APP, and I've been told to use the XMLPullParser interface.

Here is the block of code I'm working with:

XmlResourceParser parser = context.getResources().getXml(resource);

'Resource' is a an integer with the R.id. integer of the Xml file.  This is not an internal XML file, so I don't know how to work around this.

Any ideas?  Is the XmlResourceParser the wrong approach for this project?  I've seen XMLReaders used with content handlers as well.  Can you integrate these technologies together?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

what is the type of your xml source?
xmlPullParser can be used to parse any xml sources.

Comment: It's an RSS feed.  I completed that part of the project though, however, I found an example online.

Answer (score 0):

It is in my opinion the way to do this. Only problem you may encounter is when the rss feed has empty lines. The xml pullparser of android (api-level 14) jumps to the /channel if this is the case. When implementing the parser try to use the AsyncTask to start the reading of the rss feed. 
Success with the implementation.